# Load extra html on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my site I have a header, written in html, but I don't want to copy and paste it into each page. Is there a way that I could load it in when the page loads? I tried using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("injections.html", function(data) {
        var sites = ["header", "footer"];
        console.log(sites);
        for (var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++){
            console.log(i);
            site = sites[i];
            //console.log(site);
            console.log(site);
            if ($("#inject" + site).length) {
                console.log(site);
                $("#inject" + site).replaceWith($(data).find("#inject" + site).contents());
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But in firefox it only load text in Firefox and nothing in Chrome. Does anyone know how to fix my code, or a better way to do it?

Comment: Better to include it on server-side level.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Depends on your backend language.

Comment: maybe try to do it with ajax ? please could you give us whole code ? maybe we get some from console?

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński This is what I have so far: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2fwEiRB3e57MU0xUHp6R1NNclk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, that would allow you to keep the header content in a single place, is to save the header html code in a PHP file, maybe header.php.  Then save your webpages as PHP files (this won't break anything as PHP files can handle HTML, Javascript and CSS), and add this line where you want your header to be added:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

This will add the contents of header.php at that point.  Then if you need to make a change to the header code, all you need to do is change header.php, as all the webpages just point to that file.

Comment: Do I need to install something to run this locally? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yes, in order to run the files you need to have a local server installed.  Personally I use XAMPP, it works quite well.  You just put your files in the appropriate folder once your server is installed (in this case htdocs), start the server (Apache via the dashboard for XAMPP), and then put the local url into the browser (for XAMPP it's just localhost/whatever your path in the htdocs folder is.

Comment: You can download XAMPP here (though there are other alternatives such as WAMP: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: PHP files are server-side, as opposed to HTML files which are client-side, so that's why you need something like XAMPP to emulate a web server if you're going to run/test them locally.